# Fixed point theorem in ordered spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Can someone provide a proof or a source containing a proof of the following theorem

**Theorem:** Let $D$ be a subset of the cone $K$ of partially
ordered space $E,$ $F:D\rightarrow E$ be nondecreasing. If there exist
$x_{0},y_{0}\in D$ such that $x_{0}\leq y_{0},$ $\left\langle x_{0}%
,y_{0}\right\rangle \subset D $ and $x_{0},y_{0}$ are respectively lower and
upper solutions of equation $x-F\left(  x\right)  =0$, then the equation
$x-F\left(  x\right)  =0$ has minimum solution and maximum solution $x^{\ast
},y^{\ast}$ in $\left\langle x_{0},y_{0}\right\rangle $ such that $x^{\ast
}\leq y^{\ast}$, when one of the following conditions holds

1) $K$ is normal and $F$ is completely continuous;

2) $K$ is regular and $F$ is continuous;

3) $E$ is reflexive, $K$ is normal, and $F$ is continuous or weak continuous.

Comment: You should explain where this comes from and why you think it should be true.

Comment: I found it [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11117-006-2038-6), Theorem 2.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't access to the cited book.